# Can You Remove A Page From Sharepoint 2010 Analytics?

Tags: 2010, web-analytics, reports

We have a page that we'd like to avoid collecting the viewers of the page. Sort of in the vein of a page for whistleblowers, where it's difficult to see who viewed that page. I know Sharepoint collects every click and view, however we're trying to avoid showing every visitor's username in the analytics reports. I'm aware that we can't hide all traces, but we'd like to not make it so easy to see who viewed the page.

Can we turn off analytics collection for a page or remove the visitor usernames in the analytics?